# Failed to install OCI8 on PHP 5.6

Tags: php, linux, oci8

I am trying to set up on a old linux server a OCI8. On server there is set up PHP 5.6, I am following [this tutorial](https://www.syahzul.com/2016/04/06/how-to-install-oci8-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-php-5-6/) -

But I cant get pass this step  sudo pecl install oci8-2.0.10 
I always receive error. Tried to search and fix it with all given solutions but none worked for me.

[image]

Error :

```
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root6D1HIg/oci8-2.0.10/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root6D1HIg/oci8-2.0.10/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root6D1HIg/oci8-2.0.10/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20180731 -I/usr/include/php/20180731/main -I/usr/include/php/20180731/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20180731/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20180731/ext -I/usr/include/php/20180731/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/oracle/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c -o oci8.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root6D1HIg/oci8-2.0.10/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-root6D1HIg/oci8-2.0.10/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php/20180731 -I/usr/include/php/20180731/main -I/usr/include/php/20180731/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20180731/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20180731/ext -I/usr/include/php/20180731/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/oracle/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8.o
/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c:36:40: fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:196: recipe for target 'oci8.lo' failed
make: *** [oci8.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: You shouldn't post images of error messages, copy and paste the relevant part into your question instead.

Comment: I already post the image.

Comment: Posting the image is not the correct way to show an error message.

Comment: I understand but I wanted to show the whole error log, if i would copy it all it would take lot of space.  I have no problem doing that.

Comment: So we don't waste time, what solutions did you try? What PHP packages are installed (e.g do you have the development header files)?  Why not use the latest OCI8 2.0.12 ?

Comment: I just fix this, the problem was that package was 64bit but I had 32bit linux installed. I suggest to everyone that before do this, check your PHP versions and your system architecture, it will save you lot of time.